# PCA on huge (10 million+ features) datasets

Tags: matlab, pca

I am looking to extract "principal components" from huge datasets (each data point has 10 million+ features). I have about 1000 such data points. PCA only requires the co-variance matrix, which would be 1000x1000, so it's quite feasible to do PCA on the data. However the principal components still have the same dimension as the data points (10 million+). I'd like to cut this down, because my code will require reading in the principal components, and will be prohibitively slow if each principal component is several tens of megabytes.

Ideally I'd like to reduce the dimensionality of the dataset *before* applying PCA, keeping as much relevant information in the original data as possible. Any suggestions? Obviously simply downsampling the original data would work, but I'd lose high-frequency parts of my original data.

Thanks ^.^

Comment: I already wrote a post as to why this is mathematically unsound, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33350056/5211833

Comment: It's not possible for the PCs of PCA to have more features than there are observations.  See the post by Adriaan above, and also see these two posts on Cross Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28909/pca-when-the-dimensionality-is-greater-than-the-number-of-samples, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123318/why-are-there-only-n-1-principal-components-for-n-data-points-if-the-number?lq=1