# The size of my PCA coefficients is not correct

Tags: matlab, matrix, pca

I am trying to perform principal component analysis using pca and not princomp. My dataset consists of 303 samples each containing 3904 dimensions, which explains why I want to perform PCA. My data is in a matrix called Data which has a size of 303 (rows) by 3904 (columns). When I execute the PCA command with

```
[coeff,score] = pca(Data);
```

I am returned a matrix coeff of size 3904*302 and the matrix score is of size 303*302 which doesn't seem to be correct right? Online documentation suggests that coeff should be 3904*3904 (i.e. square with the dimension size of the variables, here the columns). What is going wrong here?

ps: I also tried transposing the data and this results in a coeff matrix of 303*303

Comment: You're probably trying to fit more features than the size of your sample, see for instance [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140297/pca-in-matlab-selecting-top-n-components).

Comment: @AndrasDeak *sigh* not this again.

Comment: OP: You are trying to apply PCA to data where there are more dimensions than there are data points.  It is physically impossible to do this without breaking the laws of linear independence. That's why you only get up to 303 rows as you have only 303 data points in your data set.  See Adriaan's excellent answer in the duplicate post I have marked and an explanation as to why using PCA this way will not work.