# Dimensionality reduction in HOG feature vector

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, pca

I found out the HOG feature vector of the following image in MATLAB.

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z3w0.jpg)

I used the following code.

```
I = imread('input.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(I);
[features, visualization] = extractHOGFeatures(I,'CellSize',[16 16]);
```

`features` comes out to be a `1x1944` vector and I need to reduce the dimensionality of this vector (say to `1x100`), what method should I employ for the same?

I thought of **Principal Component Analysis** and ran the following in MATLAB.

```
prinvec = pca(features);
```

`prinvec` comes out to be an empty matrix (`1944x0`). Am I doing it wrong? If not PCA, what other methods can I use to reduce the dimension?

Comment: No. Not PCA. Not again. This won't work. You have only 1 observation and almost 2k features. Impossible. Please see [this canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140297/pca-in-matlab-selecting-top-n-components/33350056#33350056) as to why this is pertinently impossible.

Comment: @Adriaan Thanks man. I just realized what I should really do. I should loop through each frame of the video and form a `Nx1944` HOG matrix and then apply PCA. Is that right?

Comment: Possibly, if `N > 1e4`, see my answer I linked on why you need some 5 times more observations than features.

Comment: Yes, can you write everything you mentioned as an answer so that I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: what features are you trying to extract and what is your ultimate goal? looping through the video and applying PCA to the final feature matrix will not necessarily give you what you want

Comment: Not sure, but what about use of a clustering algorithm to create a feature histogram and thus feature vector. You can specify the number of clusters (say 100) to produce a 1x100 vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do PCA on this, since you have more features than your single observation. Get more observations, some 10,000 presumably, and you can do PCA.

See [PCA in matlab selecting top n components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140297/pca-in-matlab-selecting-top-n-components/33350056#33350056) for the more detailed and mathematical explanation as to why this is the case.