# How to apply PCA to FFT of HOG feature?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, fft, pca

The line where features are being extracted (I have put a breakpoint for debugging

[image: The line where features are being extracted (I have put a breakpoint for debugging)]

The line where fft is being performed

[image: The line where fft is being performed]

Links to above images:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDbyL.png
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2WLb.png

This code uses fourier transform on features for some computation. I want to apply PCA on the HOG features. It seems it is doing fft on each patch, however, if I am correct I cannot apply PCA on something like 1xm features because I have one observation in each patch.

I saw this answer [Dimensionality reduction in HOG feature vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083533/dimensionality-reduction-in-hog-feature-vector?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but this doesn't help my doubt.

Is there a way around to apply PCA?

Comment: You should avoid [including source code as screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/2994596) and instead copy & paste the code directly.

Comment: @SleuthEye The code is huge and linked with multiple files. :(

Comment: The visible part in your screenshot isn't that huge.