# Why does the first principal component show least difference in my PCA?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pca, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I am using PCA on a set of facial images in MatLab.
Creating an average face and randomizing others are working fine.

In my function vectorComparison I want to see the difference on each principal component vector when using the standard deviation. But when I use eig_face_index = 1 I see less of a difference than when I use 2, or 3 etc.

The higher indexes also seem to add more color, which could be due to noise in the eigenfaces, as I am using RGB space.

Why does my initial vector show the least difference. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Here is all of the code I am using:

main.m

```
clear;clc;close all;
[imvecs,img] = loadImages();
meanval = meanValue(imvecs);
[T, D] = covarianceMatrix(imvecs, meanval);
[eigvecs, eigvals] = findEigVecs(imvecs, T, D);
eigenfaces = createEigenFaces(eigvecs, imvecs, img); 

%%
[mean_image] = createAverageFace(meanval, img);
%%
[stdev_vec] = createRandomFace(eigvals, eigvecs, imvecs, meanval, img);
%%
vectorComparison(meanval, eigvecs, stdev_vec, img, mean_image);
```

loadImages.m

```
function [imvecs,img] = loadImages()
images = dir('D:My\Path\*.png');  
imgPath = 'D:My\Path\';
img=imread([imgPath images(1).name]);
n=length(images);

for i = 1:n
    img = imread([imgPath images(i).name]);
    imvecs{i} = double(img(:));
end
return
```

meanValue.m

```
function meanval = meanValue(imvecs, imageNr)
    %Creates the mean value from our images.
    sumvec=imvecs{1};

    for i = 2:(size(imvecs,2))
        sumvec = sumvec + imvecs{i};
    end
    meanval = sumvec ./(size(imvecs,2));
return
```

covarianceMatrix.m

```
function [T, D] = covarianceMatrix(imvecs, meanval)
    D = [];
    for i = 1:size(imvecs,2),
       diff = imvecs{i} - meanval;
       D = [D, diff];
    end
    %Dimensionality reduction
    T = (D' * D) ./ (size(imvecs,2));
return
```

findEigVecs.m

```
function [eigvecs, eigvals] = findEigVecs(imvecs, T, D)
    [U,eigvals,V] = svd( T );
    eigvecs = [];
    for i = 1:size(imvecs,2),
        eigvec = D * U(:,i);
        eigvec = eigvec ./ sum(eigvec);
        eigvecs = [eigvecs, eigvec];
    end
return
```

createEigenFaces.m

```
function [eigenfaces] = createEigenFaces(eigvecs, imvecs, img)
    for i = 1:size(imvecs,2),
        eigface =  reshape(eigvecs( : , i), size(img));
        eigface = eigface - min(min(min((eigface))));
        eigface = eigface ./ max(max(max((eigface))));
        eigenfaces{i}=eigface;
        %figure;imagesc(eigface);
    end
return
```

createAverageFace.m

```
function [mean_image] = createAverageFace(meanval, img)
    mean_image = reshape(meanval, size(img));
    figure;imagesc(mean_image./255);
    title('Average Face')
return
```

createRandomFace.m

```
function [stdev_vec] = createRandomFace(eigvals, eigvecs, imvecs, meanval, img)
    stdev_vec = sqrt(diag(eigvals));
    t = (100 * rand(size(imvecs,2),1) - 50) .* stdev_vec;
    new_face1 = meanval + (eigvecs * t);
    new_face1 = reshape(new_face1, size(img));

    figure;imagesc(new_face1./255);
    title('Random Face')
return
```

vectorComparison.m

```
function [] = vectorComparison(meanval, eigvecs, stdev_vec, img, mean_image)
    t = zeros(17,1);
    eig_face_index = 1;
    t(eig_face_index) = 1000;
    t = t.*stdev_vec;

    new_face1 = meanval + (eigvecs * t);
    new_face1 = reshape(new_face1, size(img));

    new_face2 = meanval - (eigvecs * t);
    new_face2 = reshape(new_face2, size(img));

    figure;
    title('PCA Comparison')
    subplot(3,1,1), subimage(new_face1./255)
    subplot(3,1,2), subimage(mean_image./255)
    subplot(3,1,3), subimage(new_face2./255)
return
```

Comment: Are you sure you have [more observations than features in you data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140297/pca-in-matlab-selecting-top-n-components/33350056#33350056)? I.e. more rows than columns? Otherwise this'll never work, see the link.

Comment: I am pretty sure I went around this by reducing D to T, no?
Because the link's user seem to run out of memory due to his huge vectors needing to many calculations.
And I am able to print the images, so I can actually see it working. However, it seem to be less of a difference in the first principal component than in the second and so forth. It is reversed to what PCA is about. The first principal component should be the one containing most data, i.e. more differences due to variance, than the following components. I am just unclear to why it seem to be reveresed.

Comment: That's not the point of the question, nor of the answer. He has more features than observations, therefore PCA does not work. So how many features do you have and how many observations?

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood here so bear with me.
I have 17 images. This gives me 17 eigen vectors, i.e. 17 features, no? Where 16 vectors can describe 100% of my data as the last one's eigenvalue are so close to zero.
And I'm guessing my observations being my original images? Meaning 17 in this case.
It is possible to visualize each eigenface. The first one looks like it "should" and the last one is mostly noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong here.
In my function *findEigVals* I make each vector a unit vector (length 1) by deviding by the ***sum*** of the vector itself. This is possible as long as the content of the vector does range positive entries.
However, as we cannot know if we have a vector in pos or neg direction (both equally valid), we cannot use ***sum*** here.

Instead we need to replace this with ***norm***, matlab's way of stating normalization.

```
function [eigvecs, eigvals] = findEigVecs(imvecs, T, D)
    [U,eigvals,V] = svd( T );
    eigvecs = [];
    for i = 1:size(imvecs,2),
        eigvec = D * U(:,i);
        eigvec = eigvec ./ norm(eigvec);
        eigvecs = [eigvecs, eigvec];
    end
return
```

If anyone is using a version of the code above, note that the random face function will give too strong values in rgb-space.
Replace the *createRandomFace* with the following:

```
stdev_vec = sqrt(diag(eigvals));
min_range = 0;
max_range = 2;
t = ((max_range - min_range)*rand(n,1)) .* stdev_vec + min_range;
new_face1 = meanval + (eigvecs * t);
new_face1 = reshape(new_face1, size(img));

figure;imagesc(new_face1./255);
```