# Subtract mean from multi-dimensional data

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, mean, pca

I want to do a Principal Component Analysis for a large number of samples. I have no problem subtracting the mean from audio samples, since audio only has 2 dimensions and I can easily use a `for` loop .

However, this is a different case for video since each video sample has about 18-20 dimensions.

Example of content of one video file:
`whos -file sample_video_001.mat` result: `size: 54x96x19. bytes: 98496 . class: uint8. attributes: -`

How can I compute this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the mighty [`bsxfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/bsxfun.html) to calculate the mean per dimension and directly subtract it from the original array.

```
A = randi(256,54,96,19,'uint8');   %// Some random data, replace with your own
B = double(A);                     %// Cast data to double
Bav = bsxfun(@minus,B,mean(B,3));  %// Subtract the mean
```

It turned out to be a bit more complicated that I initially thought, as you have a `'uint8'` class matrix. The mean of your data along the third dimension will not be an integer most likely, and will therefore be automatically set to class `'double'`, failing a direct `bsxfun`. If you first convert your original data to `'double'` and then use `bsxfun` it will work. Possibly you might have to divide by 256 to get data in the range `[0 1]` to allow MATLAB to recognise it as a plottable format (so do `B = double(A)./256;`). You cannot go back to `'uint8'`, since you subtract a non-integer mean from your data, so the result will not be integer either.

There's a function called [`pca`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html) as well though, which is probably more suited to what you need, as it is a build-in function. Be sure that [you know how to use it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140297/pca-in-matlab-selecting-top-n-components/33350056#33350056).

Comment: I tried using `bsxfun` but an error occured: `Mixed integer class inputs are not supported`

Comment: @cathy305 please share what kind of data you have. Apparently they're not all doubles.

Comment: If I check content of first sample.. `whos -file sample_video_001.mat`, it says `size: 54x96x19.  bytes: 98496 . class: uint8.  attributes: -`

Comment: @cathy305 please edit this into the question as well. I presume the third dimension is the time axis, with the first two the x-y of the image?

Comment: Yeah, from my understanding, the third dimension is the time axis. The `uint8` is the cause of error, right? So we need to convert it to `double`? All of the video files (945 files total) are in `uint8` type though

Comment: @cathy305 I updated my solution, take care of the division though if you want to be able to plot/otherwise visualise your data.

Comment: btw, do all .avi files have data type double? Is there a way to check info about a video file such as the dimensions and frame rate?

Comment: @cathy305 I'm not very familiar with video processing. Please ask another question if you have one, and leave this one as is, if it answered your question. This helps to keep the site orderly.