# PCA for image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pca

I want to get the first principal component for an image using the built-in function `pca`. How can I do that?

I have tried the following code:

```
[COEFF, SCORE] = pca(image);
SCORE(1:size(SCORE,1),:)=0;
reconstructed_image = SCORE / COEFF + repmat(mean(image,1),size(image,1), 1);
I=reshape(reconstructed_image,[256,256]);
figure
imshow(I,[0 255])
```

I only get the fist row of the image. Any idea how can I do that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "PCA one image". What this did is *not* give you the first row, it used all rows as observations and your columns as parameters, like you'd usually set up your measurements. So it calculated the variance through all parameters, giving you a vector with the length being equal to your number of columns. You'd probably want more images to do this instead.

Please read the following answer of mine though before continuing, since I explain the main pitfalls of PCA in MATLAB there.

[PCA in matlab selecting top n components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140297/pca-in-matlab-selecting-top-n-components/33350056#33350056)

Comment: Ok, consider my image rows are images then how can I get the first pca

Comment: You are already treating each row of your image as an observation, like I wrote in my answer. With you knowledge of linear algebra you should know which is the first principal component once you've ran it through `pca`. I highly doubt it will do you any good though, but since you're not telling me what the problem is I can't solve it for you. Just a side note: there's no such thing as a "first pca" either. It's *Principal Component Analysis*, which gives you *Principal Components*. You might want to learn a thing or two about the technique before using it.